# QBitNinjaClient Get Balance c#

Tags: c#, bitcoin

I generated 5 adresses

```
1KmjtM8aibtBqbPiJahYYEwcEAH2Duk9QH
1HV55k5erZrFA3SirFLULf1rTs4sKvvqQg
1B1Tx9wXVVmmySSDSFYekM7cy7xCTybEMg
1Py6rXFPepLa7nacuRhYsJWYcfFLYE6zkw
1GRHuGiHqtuLY3A6roH7fT9bjbbiG1foWM
```

on each of them transferred money

trying to check the balance

```
public static void GetBalance(string ssAddress, bool ssIsUnspentOnly, bool ssIsTestNet, out decimal ssBalance, out decimal ssConfirmedBalance)
{
    Network net;
    if (ssIsTestNet)
        net = Network.TestNet;
    else
        net = Network.Main;
    QBitNinjaClient client = new QBitNinjaClient(net);
    var balance = client.GetBalance(new BitcoinPubKeyAddress(ssAddress), ssIsUnspentOnly).Result;
    ssBalance = 0.0M;
    ssConfirmedBalance = 0.0M;
    if (balance.Operations.Count > 0)
    {
        var unspentCoins = new List<Coin>();
        var unspentCoinsConfirmed = new List<Coin>();
        foreach (var operation in balance.Operations)
        {
            unspentCoins.AddRange(operation.ReceivedCoins.Select(coin => coin as Coin));
            if (operation.Confirmations > 0)
                unspentCoinsConfirmed.AddRange(operation.ReceivedCoins.Select(coin => coin as Coin));
        }
        ssBalance = unspentCoins.Sum(x => x.Amount.ToDecimal(MoneyUnit.BTC));
        ssConfirmedBalance = unspentCoinsConfirmed.Sum(x => x.Amount.ToDecimal(MoneyUnit.BTC));
    }
}


decimal addressBalance = 0;
decimal addressBalanceConfirmed = 0;
GetBalance("1Py6rXFPepLa7nacuRhYsJWYcfFLYE6zkw", true, false, out addressBalance, out addressBalanceConfirmed);
```

on the first three adresses shows the balance, and the last 2 no (balance.Operations.Count =0) But [link1](https://blockchain.info/tx/ffc21524760be4c4b3d4ede57d4189edac586b44dd7f62e446d1db341631d8e5), [link2](https://blockchain.info/tx/54c41856a8b11ed9971f90f6fb3fb2ab7cc591860856db84cdd60112e37ba50d).

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: when the transaction received 88 confirmations QBitNinjaClient showed the balance. Created a new transaction, it again does not see. Can I somehow reduce the number of confirmations for QBitNinjaClient ?